# Scrapy - Where can I find it on Linux Ubuntu E4.5

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, scrapy

I am working on Linux Ubuntu E4.5 (beta). I installed Scrapy (version 1 probably) with Python (version 2.7). I am trying to find the location of the actual directory that Scrapy is located in.

I tried in:

```
/Library/Frameworks/python.framework
```

but couldn't find anything

I also tried in:

```
/Uses/myuser/Library
```

I've searched inside all the bin and lib folders, and searched inside the Python installation folder, but couldn't find it.

Comment: Did you do a pip install scrapy?

Comment: `find / -name '*.py' > find.txt` run shell command as root and check `find.txt`

Comment: Like @Darec asked, it's important to know how you installed it.  Furthermore, I'm fairly certain Ubuntu E4.5 ships with both Python 3 and Python 2.7.  I don't think it comes with `pip`, though, and depending on platform, you may not have that many compiling tools anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In your python installation folder, there is a directory named `site-packages`, Scrapy should be there.

Plus, if you have installed `scrapy` using `pip`, you can do this on the terminal:

```
pip show Scrapy
```

The results will be like this:

```
---
Name: Scrapy
Version: 1.0.0rc1
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-1.0.0rc1-py2.7.egg
```

and there you can read scrapy's location directory